# Firefox seems to fail on registering a ServiceWorker for Push Notifications?

Tags: firefox

Firefox seems to fail on registering a ServiceWorker for Push Notifications, with an error `"InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"`, but the code works in Chrome and Edge, and appears to be compliant with the examples online and the spec.

I've thrown an example up on one of my test sites, https://wiegandtech.net/ - visiting it in Chrome will prompt for permission and then opt-in successfully, sending the info to the server. But Firefox prompts, doesn't complete the registration, and doesn't fire any error or throw anything into the console. When I try to debug, it seems to never return from `navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then` call - I debug in and `reg` is undefined, even though the promise says it shouldn't be. I can find no reason why this is failing. I do see in Fiddler that FF gets the worker file, so it appears to be starting the call, but never finishing? The worker is valid JavaScript, as far as I can tell. Does anyone have any documentation on how Firefox's implementation is different from Chrome's/the spec?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox requires the ServiceWorker's URL to end in .js - I was using an ASP.Net site and returning javascript but through my own controller. When I just give it the URL for the .js file itself, it now works. Would file a bug, but too non-trivial to setup a site given that ServiceWorkers require a real life site to troubleshoot, and their source code doesn't appear to be on github.

Comment: For anyone who has this issue in or around 2020 and using Firefox 75, I found the name could be anything as long as the content/type was application/javascript. However my server sent the file with a vary=* header and Firefox did not like that at all. Changing the header to vary=accept-encoding, cookie sold the problem for me.